# How do we remove labels bound to markers in google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

I am using:
>

```
ruler1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter() ,
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });
```

to create a marker and then create and bind a label to it as below:

```
    ruler1label = new Label({ map: map });
    ruler1label.bindTo('position', ruler1, 'position');
```

However, when removing the marker by:
`ruler1.setMap(null)` which removes the marker but leaves the label behind.
I tried unbinding the label to remove it by `ruler1label.setLabel(null);` but it does not work.
How can I remove these labels?
I have appended a screenshot to make it clear.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try `ruler1label.setMap(null);`. You don't have to bind/unbind, just calling that `setMap` on the label worked for me.

Comment: I had tried this, it did not work for me. Maybe there is some other issue with the code. Thanks for your reply.